# Rule for Conditional Formatting Google Sheet is Complex for me

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to create a condition for Conditional Formatting on Google Sheets.

That If `AE3` has date then `AF, AG, AH` and `AI` conditional formatting will be removed and `AE3` will be green. and this thing is working fine.

Now i have been facing issue over this thing that IF `AE3:AI3` is empty and I put a date on `AF3` it will be green and then `AH3` Conditional Formatting will removed.

Same for IF i put a date on `AG3` it will be green and then `AI3` Conditional Formatting will removed.

I have created the Conditional Formatting for the First Cell that is `AE3` but unable to create for `AF3` and `AG3` to make their link with `AH3` and `AI3`.

Let me clear one more thing IF `AE3` has date then no other cell will have any date.  IF `AF3` OR `AG3` have date then `AE3` will be empty and just have conditional formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

green for range: `AE3:AI`

```
=(DATEDIF($J3, $H3, "D")<1095)*(AE3>0)
```

red for range: `AE3:AE`

```
=($AE3="")*($D3<>"")
```

red for range: `AF3:AF,AH3:AH`

```
=($AF3="")*($AH3="")*($D3<>"")*($AE3="")
```

and red for range: `AG3:AG,AI3:AI`

```
=($AG3="")*($AI3="")*($D3<>"")*($AE3="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @player0, i was thinking its impossible but you are literally a PRo.